# Four Moderators in SPSS PROCESS for Moderated Mediation

Tags: regression, interaction, spss

I want to do moderated mediation using the PROCESS Macro (Version 4.2). Model 17 resembles what I need to do the most, however it only allows 2 moderators. I want to test 4 moderators at once.

Even using the syntax, i think there is no way around it, as there are only the zmatrix and wmatrix statements. Hayes (2018, p.619) states 'PROCESS allows up to two moderators in a model, and up to two moderators per path'. Why? I know previous versions had moderators W,Z,V and Q in the point-and-click menu but now this has been changed.

Are there any alternatives to that within PROCESS?